# How to sample data such that sample attribute means optimally match arbitrary target attribute means?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, sampling

I have a very large dataset **D** (>100 million samples) with attribute/feature set **F** (<100 features). I need to create a sample set **S** such that the mean error between the feature averages of **S** (**Fs**) and some given array of target feature values (**Ft**) is minimized. We do not have any other information about the target data (its distribution, variances etc.), so we are free to make any assumptions. Also, while we would like **S** to be as large as possible, small sizes are also acceptable (lowest at about 10000 samples).

I have tried the following approaches so far:

- Fit target values belong to specific distribution (Normal, Poisson etc.). Get the corresponding PDF values for each point in **D**. Get probabilities by multiplying the values for each feature for each point. Do weighted sampling on the probability set.
- Get distance (cosine/Manhattan) between the target vector and each point in **D**. Transform output to interpret as probabilities. Carry out weighted sampling.

I have also been looking into MCMC sampling but not sure how to go about fitting it to this specific problem.

What could be some potential approaches that could work well?

Comment: First thought is to look into balanced sampling methods. Stratified sampling is a special case. The book "Sampling and Estimation from Finite Populations" by Yves Tille has a good overview. Could you explain the purpose of your sample? What is it that you want to use the sample for, and why use it instead of the larger dataset? We can guess, but it would be good to clarify to make sure the answers are useful.

Comment: between the two proposed approaches, there is no better one in principle. the first one is basically the same as the second if you use a distance based on fitted log-probability.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed here is find sample weights $w_j^*$ such that $X w^* = F_t$, and construct **S**, a weighted-sampled of **D**, using  sample weights $w^*$.

Let $M$ equal the number of attributes $(M \lt 10^2)$.
Let $N$ equal the number of observations $(N \gt 10^8)$.
Consider the $N$ observations in the dataset **D** as $M$-length column vectors $f_j$.

$$
\begin{align}
X = \left[ f_1 \ldots  f_j \ldots f_N\right]
\end{align}
$$

This is a rank $M$ problem, $M \ll N$. Let $\bar{w}$ be the equal weight vector, with vector elements $\bar{w}_j = N^{-1}$  $\forall j=1,\ldots,N$.

There are multiple solutions for weighting $10^8$ observations to match $10^2$ constraints.  Treating this as a regularized least squares problem, where weights $w^*$ near $\bar{w}$ are desired,
$$
\begin{align}
w^* &= \bar{w} + \Delta w\quad, \\
\Delta w &= (X^\textrm{T}X + \lambda I_N)^{-1}X^\textrm{T}
\left( 
F_t - X \bar{w}\right)\quad.
\end{align}
$$

Using the [Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula, $B=A+UV$, where $UV$ represents a low-rank $M (<100)$ update to $A$, and $A$ is readily invertible,
$$
B^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1} U(I_M + V A^{-1} U)^{-1} V A^{-1} \quad,
$$
where the required inverse matrix $(I_M + V A^{-1} U)^{-1}$ is
size $M \times M$ (managable).

Here $A = \lambda I_N, \quad A^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} I_N, \quad U=X^\textrm{T}, \quad V=X$,

$$
B^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} I_N - \lambda^{-2} X^{T}(I_M + \lambda^{-1}X X^{T})^{-1} X \quad.
$$

Regularized least squares will minimize the sum of squared coefficients,
$$
\begin{align}
&\Delta w = w^* - \bar{w}\quad, \\
&\min \left(\Delta w\right) ^\textrm{T} \left(\Delta w\right) \quad.
\end{align}
$$

Combining these components,
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta w &= \left(\lambda^{-1} I_N - \lambda^{-2} X^{T}\left(I_M + \lambda^{-1}X X^{T}\right)^{-1} X \right) X^\textrm{T} 
\left( 
F_t - X \bar{w}\right)\quad, \\
w^* &= \bar{w} + \Delta w \quad.
\end{align}
$$

I don't anticipate that you will obtain negative $w_j^*$, but if you do, drop those observations $j : w_j^* < 0 $ from consideration and re-solve for $w^*$.

Comment: First of: That is a brilliant approach to this problem. Wow! Still I do have three questions: 1) This is specifically ridge regression(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression) right, so Melsauce could maybe look for a corresponding Python library? 2) $\sum_i w^*_i = 1$ wasn't included, but you could always just rescale correct? 3) Does $\lambda$ have to be large because $X^TX$ is so "very" singular or is that not a thing?

Comment: @LukasLohse: 1) the problem is framed as a ridge regression problem. A linear algebra package, such as https://netlib.org/lapack/ would be my preference. The "magic" is in the tiny matrix inversion, dimension $M \times M$, not $N \times N$ (which naïve ridge regression might implement). 2) yes, add an additional element to the feature vector for each record $x_{M+1,j} = 1$, and $(F_t-X\bar{w})_{M+1} = 0$ (the sum of changes to the equal weight vector should be zero). 3) the above algorithm does not invert $X^\textrm{T} X$, but rather $I_M + \lambda^{-1}X X^{T}$. Experiment with $\lambda$.

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.lapack.html#module-scipy.linalg.lapack for a Python implementation of LAPACK (**L**inear **A**lgebra **PACK**age). Disclosure: I don't code in Python, dig around as needed.

Comment: The above tries to minimally impact the distribution of **D** while constrained to $F_t$.  This is in the spirit of: Zhu, Song Chun, Yingnian Wu, and David Mumford. "Filters, random fields and maximum entropy (FRAME): Towards a unified theory for texture modeling." International Journal of Computer Vision 27.2 (1998): 107-126.